# My Math Seems Fine, but My Drawlines Look Weird. [Hexagon Grid]

Tags: vb.net

I think I just need a fresh set of eyes to look at this. Or perhaps it's an issue with my numbers not being specific enough. I'm a beginner at programming and my only hunch is recursion.

[image: Hexagonal grid]

Essentially, my hexagons are incorrectly positioned in some rows, but not others and I want them to all be smooth.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
        'Side Length
        Dim side As Integer = 25
        'Grid Width
        Dim width As Integer = 10
        'Grid Height
        Dim height As Integer = 10
        'Starting X
        Dim startX As Integer = 100
        'Starting Y
        Dim startY As Integer = 100
        'Hexagon Border
        Dim borderPen As New Pen(Brushes.Gray, 1)

        For i = 1 To width Step 1
            For j = 1 To height Step 1

                Dim apothem As Integer = (Math.Sqrt(3) * side / 2)
                Dim half As Integer = (side / 2)
                Dim centerX As Integer = (startX + (side * i * 1.5))
                Dim centerY As Integer = (startY + (apothem * j * 2))

                If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
                    centerY += apothem
                End If

                e.Graphics.DrawLine(borderPen, (centerX - half), (centerY + apothem), (centerX + half), (centerY + apothem))
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(borderPen, (centerX + half), (centerY + apothem), (centerX + side), (centerY))
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(borderPen, (centerX + side), (centerY), (centerX + half), (centerY - apothem))
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(borderPen, (centerX + half), (centerY - apothem), (centerX - half), (centerY - apothem))
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(borderPen, (centerX - half), (centerY - apothem), (centerX - side), (centerY))
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(borderPen, (centerX - side), (centerY), (centerX - half), (centerY + apothem))
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: So write some test code.  Draw one hexagon at a time and see exactly where/when things go wrong and then you can observe the actual values in use at the time.  You fix bugs by debugging and testing, not just by reading code.

Comment: Also, I would be inclined to look at a single call to `DrawLines` rather than multiple calls to `DrawLine`. Finally, you should be disposing your `Pen`, which you should do by creating it with a `Using` statement.

Comment: In the process of doing that. The only thing that makes my hexagons smooth is when the length of the side is an even number. Odd numbers may not be as accurate I suppose. I'll continue to tinker. And I'll look into those improvements! Thanks!

Comment: Before debugging, set Option Strict On. Correct the assignments (and the errors) using all floating points values (single). Also, note that there's a `e.Graphics.DrawLines()` method (plural) but also `e.Graphics.DrawPolygon()`. All of those accept floating point positions. You could also explore `GraphicsPath.AddPolygon()`. Since you're using a Pen on size 1, you could use a StockObject (`Pens.Gray`) which doesn't need disposing of. Or a pre-defined custom Pen that you Dispose() of at the end (when closing the Form/App)

Comment: Put `Option Strict On` at the very top before `Public Class Form1`. VS will then highlight your problem. Replace the highlighted `Integer`s with `Single` and it will look smooth.

Comment: Alternatively: Draw the hexagon once onto a separate Image and then just draw that image multiple times onto the form

Comment: I just woke up, but have to go to school. I'll tinker with all of your guys' ideas when I get home in eightish hours. Thanks again!

Comment: Try changing borderPen color as you increment width, that was you can identify which hexagon is the problem (looks row 4, might be rows 3 & 5 etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tinkered with the suggestions you guys commented and fixed the bug I was having. I wasn't using correct data types. Also, I utilized e.Graphics.Drawlines and the StockObject tip for pens and disposing of them. Thanks, again!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVL5V.jpg

If there's any other improvements I can make to my code feel free to comment them.

```
Option Strict On
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles 
Me.Paint
        'Side Length
        Dim side As Single = 30
        'Grid Width
        Dim width As Single = 10
        'Grid Height
        Dim height As Single = 5
        'Starting X
        Dim startX As Single = 0
        'Starting Y
        Dim startY As Single = 0

        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
        e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half

        Dim apothem As Single = CSng(Math.Sqrt(3) * side / 2.0F)
        Dim half As Single = (side / 2)

        For i = 1 To width Step 1
            For j = 1 To height Step 1
                Dim centerX As Single = (startX + (side * i * 1.5F))
                Dim centerY As Single = (startY + (apothem * j * 2))

                If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
                    centerY += apothem
                End If

                Dim points As New List(Of PointF)

                points.Add(New PointF((centerX - half), (centerY + apothem)))
                points.Add(New PointF((centerX + half), (centerY + apothem)))
                points.Add(New PointF((centerX + side), (centerY)))
                points.Add(New PointF((centerX + half), (centerY - apothem)))
                points.Add(New PointF((centerX - half), (centerY - apothem)))
                points.Add(New PointF((centerX - side), (centerY)))
                points.Add(New PointF((centerX - half), (centerY + apothem)))

                e.Graphics.DrawLines(Pens.Gray, points.ToArray())
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Add `e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias` and 
`e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half` before the loop. See the difference. + You should use single, not double. In your loop you have constant casts from double to single in `points.Add()` +  `Dim apothem` and `Dim half` should be moved outside the loop. You have to calculate those just once.

Comment: Cast to single when needed (e.g., `CSng((Math.Sqrt(3) / 2.0F) * side)`). Use single values for all the other varialbles: side, width etc. Btw, `width` and `height` are bad names (same as Controls properties)). Use something like `GridWidth`, `GridHeight` etc.

Comment: I did the 2dGraphics suggestions and I liked them, but you've lost me on the casting integers part.

Comment: Simple. All of you local variables should be declared as `Single`. When you do, you'll have consistent behaviour on all the calculations. You need to use a `List(Of PointF)` and then add a `New PointF()` and not cast again to `Integer`. That's bad. Use the `PointF` structure, it accepts a `Single` data type. => Do not use `Integers` in this procedure anywhere.

Comment: I edited my code in my answer to fit your suggestions. Constant casts fixed and improved graphics. Thanks!